# What is the exact methodology of Magento Front-end exam?

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, certification

I'm bit confused about the number of questions appeared in Magento front-end exam. What is the exact number of questions it gives? What is the passing mark? Are there any optional questions in the exam or all the questions are mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from the official site http://magento.com/training/catalog/front-end-developer-certification:

> ABOUT THE EXAM
>
> - 86 multiple-choice questions (65 scored and 16 unscored)
> - 120 minutes to complete the exam
> - Each question on the exam tests a skill that applies to both Community Edition v.1.8 and Enterprise Edition v.1.13.
> - No hard-copy or online materials may be referenced during the exam